# Минимизация булевых функций (получение МДНФ)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, дискретная-математика, булева-алгебра

Ещё в прошлом году у меня был курс *дискретной математики*, и с её основами я знаком. Мне бы хотелось, что бы вы помогли мне с написанием алгоритма получения **ДНФ**, и объяснения того, как из **ДНФ** перейти в **МДНФ**.

Я ищу любой пример реализации этой задачи, не обязательно на C++. Главное, что бы был понятен алгоритм получения **ДНФ** и **МДНФ**. Было бы здорово, если бы вы развёрнуто прокомментировали алгоритм (что на входе, что на выходе, и т.д.).

Возможно я не туда пишу, но знаю, что тут есть умные люди, а других хороших сервисов я не знаю. Буду рад, если вы подскажите другие сервисы, на которых я мог бы задать этот вопрос.

Comment: Почитайте про алгоритм минимизации Квайна-МакКласки. Это тот же алгоритм Квайна, но переделанный так, что его очень удобно реализовывать на машине.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите вот [этот](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mini-qmc/quine_mc_cluskey_v0.2.zip) проект. Если ссылка со временем окажется битой - гуглите 
[Quine-McCluskey minimizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mini-qmc/).